# Html how to inlcude script in my template?

Tags: javascript, html, django, typescript, django-templates

I have a question for you.

I'm trying to create a file js which contains all my chart in my html pages. The structure are the following:

```
___base.html
___scripts.html
___conto_economico.html
___charts.html
```

In my base.html I have included the scripts.html in the following manner:

```
{% block javascript %}
{% include 'adminlte/lib/_scripts.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

In my scripts.html I have included all scripts, also the `charts.js` file

```
{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'charts/charts.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Finally, in conto_economico.html I have extends my base and include the scripts.html in the following manner:

```
{% extends 'adminlte/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'adminlte/lib/_scripts.html' %}
.....
<canvas class=" w-100 " id="chart"  height="180" ></canvas>
......
{% endblock content %}
```

But my "chart" does not uploaded in my page. Where is the error?

**EDIT**

My setting stati file are the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT= [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

In my I have two static folder:

1. The first one in `my_project/static`
2. The second one in my `v_env\Lib\site-packages\adminlte3\static` that is where I have my base.html file and scripts file.

Could be this one the problem?

Comment: Are you configured static files ?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT= [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
`

Comment: @ Muhammad Faizan Fareed I have edited my answer with more details

Comment: Put your all static files into static directory instead of this

Answer (score 0):

Your base.html and _scripts.html are in same folder. Just do:

```
{% include '_scripts.html' %}
```

Comment: Nope my scripts.html file contains all the scripts.js, it is a container

Comment: Sometimes Django have some problems with the browser. So, delete change the name of the template of the include (try using without "_" and same name of other templates. delete the include and place it closer to the html code far from the {% block content %} tag. In addition, add again a new include tag and see whether it works.